# Custom Input For Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd, command, prompt

What I'm looking for seems to be very simple. I want to run a command prompt line, but have it to be easily editable for anyone to use. There are multiple commands to this script, but only one part needs to be changed, and asks the user for a custom input. I'm sure this is already online, however after looking for hours and finding nothing as I have no clue what it would even be called, this is my last resort. Any help would be appreciated as I'm not even quite sure how to describe this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but if I understand correctly it sounds like you are trying to read user input (ie. prompt the user for input) from a batch file. If so, this should work for you:

```
set /p CustomInput="Please enter blah blah blah.."
```

Then you can use `%CustomInput%` as a variable in the script.

Comment: Yes, that is exactually what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may also add this line:

> goto %CustomInput%